# how to create the sql_query

Tags: php, mysql

I have created some filters in php.3 of them are aimming 1 table. The 4th is aimming another table.
first table is :

```
id_of_orders :
id_order(int) time(NOW) username(varchar) price(decimal)
```

the second one is :

```
order :
 order_id(int)  product(varchar) price (decimal)
```

`order.order_id` is refered to the `id_of_orders.id_order`

Table id_of_orders is like a mapper to the orders table (`id_of_orders.id_order` has unique numbers).
Table orders contains many orders some of them have same `order_id`

I want to return the id_of_orders.id_order which contain the `order.product=='proion'`

The query that i use is this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM id_of_orders WHERE 1=1";
if(!empty($_SESSION['employees']))
  $query .= " AND id_of_orders.username='$_SESSION[employees]'";
if(!empty($_SESSION['timis']))
  $query .= " AND id_of_orders.price='$_SESSION[timis]'";
if(!empty($_SESSION['dates']))
  $query .= " AND DATE(time)='$_SESSION[dates]'";
//if(!empty($_SESSION['proions']))
 // $query .= " AND (orders.product='$_SESSION[proions]' && id_of_orders.id_order==orders.order_id)";

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a query like

```sql
SELECT o.* 
  FROM id_of_orders i JOIN
(
  SELECT order_id
    FROM orders
   WHERE product = 'proion'
   GROUP BY order_id
) q ON i.id_order = q.order_id
 WHERE o.username = ?
   AND o.price = ?
   AND DATE(time) = ?
```

or

```sql
SELECT i.id_order, i.time, i.username, i.price 
  FROM id_of_orders i JOIN orders o
    ON i.id_order = o.order_id
 WHERE 1 = 1
   AND o.product = 'proion'
   AND o.username = ?
   AND o.price = ?
   AND DATE(time) = ?
 GROUP BY i.id_order, i.time, i.username, i.price
```

Comment: What do you mean *...i cant use another query...*? You build it in your code. See updated answer. I've added your other filtering conditions (may be that is what you've meant).

Comment: well i used this for a start and i got nothing : 
"SELECT i.id_order, i.time, i.username, i.price 
 FROM id_of_orders i JOIN `order` o
    ON i.id_order = o.order_id
 WHERE 1 = 1" ;

Comment: In your question it is 'order'. Anyway did it help?

Comment: It gave me a picture of how i should remake it. But the general idea is this, now i will modify it because I am also, paging those filters and export them as xml. Thanks!